# USER_PERMISSION_DENIED Error while making google ads api request

Tags: google-ads-api

I am getting a USER_PERMISSION_DENIED error while making google ads API call. Upon googling I got to know that we need to pass login customer id and client customer id while making API call?

1. I want to understand what is the difference between login customer id and client customer id?
2. How do I get login customer id and client customer id ?
3. When do I have to use both login customer id and client customer id while making API call?
   Some sample code examples to use both login customer id and client customer id using java library would be helpful